# Unable to receive last returning value in promise based async/await architecture in node, express and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await, node-async

I am new to async and await. Every thing works fine but in final output last value in result, mcount is not returning. Means aggregation output is returning slowly.

Profile and Userinfo are two separate schemas.

```
flist (req, res){
    Profile.findById(req.user)
    .select('list.users -_id')
    .exec(function (err, result){
      if(err){
        res.status(400).send("Invalid request")
      }
      if(result.list.users.length >= 1){
          uinfo(result.list.users, req.user)
          .then(value =>{           
            console.log(value)
              res.status(200).send({
                friends : value
              })
          })
          .catch(err => {
              res.status(400).send("Invalid request")
            })          
      }else{
        res.status(200).send("No result")
      }
    })
  }
```

list.users is nested object with id fields. Below one is uinfo function

```
async function uinfo(data, user){
    const arr = []
    for(let i of data){
      await Userinfo.findById(i.id, 'name', function(err, success){
        if(err){
          res.status(400).send("Invalid request")
        }
        const obj = success.toObject()
        Profile.aggregate([{"$match": {"_id": {"$in": [user, i.id]}}}, {"$unwind": "$list.users"}, {"$group": {_id: "$list.users.id", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {count: 2}}, {$project: {_id: 1}}], function(err, result){
          if(err){
            res.status(400).send("Invalid request")
          }
          if(result.length >= 1){
            obj.mcount = result.length
          }
          else{
            obj.mcount = 0
          }
        })
      arr.push(obj)

      })
    }
    return arr
}
```

Below one is the output where in last one it is missing mcount.

```
   [   { _id: 5aba75ef60b6c909a859a312,
    name: 'user1',
    mcount: 0 },
  { _id: 5abbc6fcafafad143a4d4f85,
    name: 'user2',
    mcount: 1 },
  { _id: 5aba761160b6c909a859a318, name: 'user3' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `await` in a for loop like this can really slow you down sometimes, see [In JavaScript, does using `await` inside a loop block the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410119/in-javascript-does-using-await-inside-a-loop-block-the-loop/44410481). What you might do instead is something like this:

```
const arr = await Promise.all(data.map(i => {
   // whatever stuff you want to do with the data
}))
return arr
```

I don't know if this will solve the problem with the last one, but it will speed up what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing syntaxes with `await-async`, `callback`, **and** `Promise`. Don't do that.

This is the best I could do. I would seriously consider a rewrite and only use `async-await`. The code below is **untested**.

Error handling is omitted.

```
const flist = async (req, res) => {
    const users = await Profile.findById(req.user)
        .select('list.users -_id')
        .exec()

    if (result.list.users.length >= 1) {
        const friends = await uinfo(result.list.users, req.user)
        res.status(200).json({
            friends
        })
    } else {
        res.status(400).json()
    }
}

async function uinfo(data, user) {
    const arr = []
    const promises = []

    // You can not mix synchronous with asynchronous operations
    for (const i of data) {
        promises.push(Userinfo.findById(i.id, 'name').exec())
    }

    // Wait for all Promises to complete.
    // Returns an array of values from the iteration above
    const success = await Promise.all(promises)

    // 0 is "falsey"
    if (!success.length) {
        // error
    }

    // Since you're only looking for one user, if the above check is fine then pull it from the array
    const obj = success[0].toObject()

    const result = await Profile
        .aggregate([{"$match": {"_id": {"$in": [user, obj.id]}}}, {"$unwind": "$list.users"}, {"$group": {_id: "$list.users.id", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {count: 2}}, {$project: {_id: 1}}])
        .exec()

    if (result.length >= 1) {
        obj.mcount = result.length
    } else {
        obj.mcount = 0
    }

    arr.push(obj)

    return arr
}
```

Comment: And result also has to loop through for each users data.

Comment: result has to loop through in aggregation so i used for loop as you wrote for findById but last document is missing mcount.