# Chain promises while condition is true

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to get all pages requsted via XHR using JS `Promise`.

For me it's relatively trivial to get this with recursive callbacks, but how I can achieve this with promises?

Simplified example without promises:

```
class Foo {
    getPages(callback, pagesCount)
    {
        if (typeof(pagesCount) === 'undefined') {
            pagesCount = 0;
        }

        // Let's say its async XHR
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            ++pagesCount;
            // Let's say that in 90% of cases we will get a full page
            if (Math.random() < 0.9) {
                console.log('Page received!');
                this.getPages(callback, pagesCount);
            } else {
                console.log('Last page received!');
                callback(pagesCount);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    doStuff(pagesCount)
    {
        console.log('Total pages: ' + pagesCount);
    }

    run()
    {
        this.getPages(this.doStuff);
    }
}

(new Foo()).run();
```

And I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
class Foo {
    getPages()
    {
        ...
    }

    doStuff(pagesCount)
    {
        console.log('Total pages: ' + pagesCount);
    }

    run()
    {
        this.getPages().then(this.doStuff);
    }
}

(new Foo()).run();
```

Comment: This currently reads as a request for a tutorial, is that what you intended?

Comment: You can use `await` inside a `while` loop.

Comment: i read your question at least like 4 times and still didnt understand a thing. May be you will consider adding some samples showing what you want ?

Comment: @jared-smith, I hope to get a hint \ a link to an article or an example \ a snippet of code with the basic logic of chaining promises in this case \ whatever. I understand your question, I'm not trying to solve my prooblem using someone else, I just want to ask for help, because already unsuccessfully trying to solve this problem for several hours.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov post your code! We can help you with your code but requesting an off-site resource is off-topic here.

Comment: @jared-smith, okay, I'll post example with callback in a few minutes.

Comment: @jared-smith, added some code snippets to illustrate.

Comment: @JaredSmith, and I'm not requesting off-site, but if the answer to my question I can get by following the link, then I do not see the point of copying the essence here.

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense. Post *actual* code.

Comment: @JaredSmith, why it doesnt make any sense? Its work and illustrate what I want to achieve without excess code. In two words - I can request page though API, max 100 items per page. I want to load all pages and I know that it is last page when items count less than 100. When I loaded all pages I want to proceed. I believe that code with promises will be more readable.

Comment: @Barmar, can you provide simple example, please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410119/in-javascript-does-using-await-inside-a-loop-block-the-loop it shows how do to it in `for` loop, but `while` is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the advent of `async/await` recursive promises were indeed impossible. You'd have to convert the promise into a callback friendly code and do your recursion using callbacks.

However, `async/await` allows you to do what you want:

```
async getPages(pagesCount)
{
    if (typeof(pagesCount) === 'undefined') {
        pagesCount = 0;
    }

    // Let's say its async XHR
    while () {

        // Call promisified XHR like this:
        // xhrResult = await XHR();

        // Call callback based XHR like this: 
        // xhrResult = await new Promise(function(ok,err){
        //   XHR(function (error, result) {
        //     if (error) {
        //       err(error)
        //   } else {
        //       ok(result)
        //   }    
        // });

        if (Math.random() < 0.9) {
            console.log('Page received!');
            return await getPages(pagesCount);
        } else {
            console.log('Last page received!');
            return pagesCount;
        }
    };
}
```

Note: all functions marked `async` return promises. So now you can do:

```
getPages(100).then(count => console.log(count + ' pages left'))
```

Comment: `Before the advent of async/await recursive promises were indeed impossible` - I disagree

Comment: Does it matter?