# Deno file server hangs on client refresh

Tags: javascript, http, deno

I've implemented a `deno` file server like this:

```js
import { WebServerSettings } from "../types.ts";

import {
    StatusCodes,
    ReasonPhrases
} from "https://deno.land/x/https_status_codes@v1.2.0/mod.ts";

import { mime } from "https://deno.land/x/mimetypes@v1.0.0/mod.ts";

export class WebServer {
    settings:WebServerSettings;

    constructor(settings:WebServerSettings){
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    async start(){
        const server = Deno.listen(this.settings);
        console.log(`Web Server up and running on port ${this.settings.port}`);

        for await (const connection of server){
            this.handle(connection).catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    }

    private async handle(connection: Deno.Conn){
        const httpConnection = Deno.serveHttp(connection);
        for await (const requestEvent of httpConnection){
            const url = new URL(requestEvent.request.url);
            let filepath = decodeURIComponent(url.pathname);
            
            const root:string = (filepath.match(/\/[^\/]*/) || [""])[0];
            const local = new Map(Object.entries(this.settings.dirs)).get(root) || 
                this.settings.dirs.default + root;

            filepath = local + 
                filepath.replace(/^\/?$/, "/index.html")
                .replace(root, "");

            let file;
            try {
                file = await Deno.open(filepath, { read: true });
            } catch {
                const response = new Response(
                    ReasonPhrases.NOT_FOUND, { status: StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND });
    
                await requestEvent.respondWith(response);
                return;
            }

            const contentType = mime.getType(filepath) || "application/octet-stream";

            await requestEvent.respondWith(
                new Response(file.readable, { 
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": contentType
                    }}));
        }
    }
}
```

It's a slight modification of the deno file server available on deno examples. Essentially allows statically mapping some folders and adds `Content-Type` header to response.
On my browser I enter the following URL `http://localhost:8080` and `index.html` is served correctly the first time:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <title>Client</title>
        <script src="js/protobuf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

But if I hit the refresh button on browser, the page loading hangs forever and the server doesn't receive any request. But if then I hit stop and refresh again, the page is then loaded. This is ALWAYS reproducible on any browser.
The issue is related to this line

```html
<script src="js/protobuf.min.js"></script>
```

If I comment it out or if I change the `src` to `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/protobufjs@7.X.X/dist/protobuf.js`, everything works fine.
It seems that the server has troubles serving "bigger" files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

The core problem is that you are "blocking" the [`AsyncIterable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) [`httpConnection`](https://deno.land/api@v1.30.3?s=Deno.HttpConn) by [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)ing inside its associated [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of):

```ts
for await (const requestEvent of httpConnection) {
  // Don't await in this code block
}
```

Suggestion: Just use the [`serve`](https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/http/server.ts?s=serve) function from [`https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/http/server.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/http/server.ts) instead of the low level HTTP APIs — it will help you avoid this and other similarly subtle issues (your code doesn't contain any logic that uses the low level API capabilities anyway, so you don't need it).

Refs:

- [Stack Overflow - In JavaScript, does using await inside a loop block the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44410119/438273)
- [GitHub - denoland/deno#13362: Some (but not all) files fail to be served after page refresh](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13362)

---

### Reproducible problem and fix

You haven't provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I'll use the code you did show to demonstrate the issue and show how to fix the specific issue that you asked about — in this way, you and everyone else reading this will have everything needed to follow along and reproduce it. Here are the files in the reproduction:

I'll put the files-to-be-served in a `./public` directory:

`./public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <meta lang="en">
        <title>Client</title>
        <script src="js/protobuf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

> `cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/protobufjs@7.X.X/dist/protobuf.js`

You mentioned the above URL pattern in the question, but didn't show the local file, so I'll download a copy of this file to `./public/js/protobuf.min.js` and show its byte length:

```txt
% curl -fsSL 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/protobufjs@7.2.2/dist/protobuf.min.js' > public/js/protobuf.min.js

% wc -c < public/js/protobuf.min.js
   74208
```

Here's the code in the module from your question:

`./server.ts`:

```ts
// You didn't show this file in your question,
// so I've created a substitute for it below on line 12:
// import { WebServerSettings } from "../types.ts";

import {
  ReasonPhrases,
  StatusCodes,
} from "https://deno.land/x/https_status_codes@v1.2.0/mod.ts";

import { mime } from "https://deno.land/x/mimetypes@v1.0.0/mod.ts";

export type WebServerSettings = Parameters<typeof Deno.listen>[0] & {
  dirs: Partial<Record<string, string>> & { default: string };
};

export class WebServer {
  settings: WebServerSettings;

  constructor(settings: WebServerSettings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  async start() {
    const server = Deno.listen(this.settings);
    console.log(`Web Server up and running on port ${this.settings.port}`);

    for await (const connection of server) {
      this.handle(connection).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }
  }

  private async handle(connection: Deno.Conn) {
    const httpConnection = Deno.serveHttp(connection);
    for await (const requestEvent of httpConnection) {
      const url = new URL(requestEvent.request.url);
      let filepath = decodeURIComponent(url.pathname);

      const root: string = (filepath.match(/\/[^\/]*/) || [""])[0];
      const local = new Map(Object.entries(this.settings.dirs)).get(root) ||
        this.settings.dirs.default + root;

      filepath = local +
        filepath.replace(/^\/?$/, "/index.html")
          .replace(root, "");

      let file;
      try {
        file = await Deno.open(filepath, { read: true });
      } catch {
        const response = new Response(
          ReasonPhrases.NOT_FOUND,
          { status: StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND },
        );

        await requestEvent.respondWith(response);
        return;
      }

      const contentType = mime.getType(filepath) || "application/octet-stream";

      await requestEvent.respondWith(
        new Response(file.readable, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": contentType,
          },
        }),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And here's a module that imports it and starts a server at the details in your question:

> `http://localhost:8080`

`./main.ts`:

```ts
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/path/mod.ts";
import { WebServer, type WebServerSettings } from "./server.ts";

const defaultDir = path.join(
  path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url)),
  "public",
);

const settings: WebServerSettings = {
  dirs: { default: defaultDir },
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 8080,
};

await new WebServer(settings).start();
```

Now, running this module will reproduce the issue that you described:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.30.3 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.9.4

% deno run --allow-net=localhost:8080 --allow-read=. main.ts
Web Server up and running on port 8080
```

On the first page load, the requested resources are received, as shown in the waterfall and log views of [Chrome's dev tools network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/):

[image: network1]

However, on a refresh of the page, the request stalls (the server doesn't respond) and the log shows "*Pending...*":

[image: network2]

This is the issue that you described.

Back in the terminal, stop the server with `ctrl+c`.

In order not to block the request loop, you must not `await` inside it. One way to refactor your `./server.ts` code is to split the `handle` method into two methods:

```ts
export class WebServer {
  settings: WebServerSettings;

  constructor(settings: WebServerSettings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  async start() {
    const server = Deno.listen(this.settings);
    console.log(`Web Server up and running on port ${this.settings.port}`);

    for await (const connection of server) {
      this.handleConn(connection).catch((ex) => console.error(ex));
    }
  }

  private async handleConn(connection: Deno.Conn) {
    const httpConnection = Deno.serveHttp(connection);
    for await (const requestEvent of httpConnection) {
      requestEvent.respondWith(this.handleRequest(requestEvent.request))
        .catch((ex) => console.error(ex));
    }
  }

  private async handleRequest(request: Request): Promise<Response> {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    let filepath = decodeURIComponent(url.pathname);

    const root: string = (filepath.match(/\/[^\/]*/) || [""])[0];
    const local = new Map(Object.entries(this.settings.dirs)).get(root) ||
      this.settings.dirs.default + root;

    filepath = local +
      filepath.replace(/^\/?$/, "/index.html")
        .replace(root, "");

    let file: Deno.FsFile;
    try {
      file = await Deno.open(filepath, { read: true });
    } catch {
      return new Response(
        ReasonPhrases.NOT_FOUND,
        { status: StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND },
      );
    }

    const contentType = mime.getType(filepath) || "application/octet-stream";

    return new Response(file.readable, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": contentType,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

In the modified code above, the `await` keyword is never used directly within any of the `for await...of` loops, which prevents blocking of the `AsyncIterator`s which are responsible for responding to connections and requests.

Now, when the server is run, all network logs look like this, no matter how many times the page is refreshed:

[image: network3]

---

As mentioned at the beginning: no logic in your code uses features of the low level HTTP APIs. You can just use the `serve` function instead:

`./server.ts`:

```ts
import {
  serve,
  type ServeInit,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/http/server.ts";

import {
  ReasonPhrases,
  StatusCodes,
} from "https://deno.land/x/https_status_codes@v1.2.0/mod.ts";

import { mime } from "https://deno.land/x/mimetypes@v1.0.0/mod.ts";

export type WebServerSettings = ServeInit & {
  dirs: Partial<Record<string, string>> & { default: string };
};

export class WebServer {
  settings: WebServerSettings;

  constructor(settings: WebServerSettings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  start() {
    const onListen = this.settings.onListen ??
      (({ port }) => console.log(`Web Server up and running on port ${port}`));
    return serve(this.handleRequest, { ...this.settings, onListen });
  }

  private handleRequest = async (request: Request): Promise<Response> => {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    let filepath = decodeURIComponent(url.pathname);

    const root: string = (filepath.match(/\/[^\/]*/) || [""])[0];
    const local = new Map(Object.entries(this.settings.dirs)).get(root) ||
      this.settings.dirs.default + root;

    filepath = local +
      filepath.replace(/^\/?$/, "/index.html")
        .replace(root, "");

    let file: Deno.FsFile;
    try {
      file = await Deno.open(filepath, { read: true });
    } catch {
      return new Response(
        ReasonPhrases.NOT_FOUND,
        { status: StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND },
      );
    }

    const contentType = mime.getType(filepath) || "application/octet-stream";

    return new Response(file.readable, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": contentType,
      },
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the deep and detailed explanation!