# Playwright/Puppeteer automation script doesn't do `async...await` in `for..loop` properly for `/signup` page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, async-await, puppeteer, playwright

So I'm trying to automate rate-limit requests with playwright automation script.

But the problem is it keeps signing up for `test0@example.com` email & therefore keeps giving `Email already used` error.

I thought I am using `async...await` right with `for...loop` but apparently not.

```js
import { chromium } from 'playwright'

async function main() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/signup')
    await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded')

    await page.fill('input[name="email"]', `test${i}@example.com`)
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]')

    await page.waitForURL('http://localhost:3000/verify-email')
    // await page.waitForSelector('#verify-email-form', {
    //   state: 'visible',
    //   timeout: 0,
    // })

    console.log(i)
  }

  await page.close()
  await browser.close()
}

main()
```

I tried the commented code too above but that doesn't work either.

My server script gives this:

```json
{ email: 'test0@example.com' }
{ user: [], unique: true }
{ email: 'test0@example.com' }
{
  user: [
    {
      id: '01HNPK1GRM5ZHWXZBV1K2R3A9B',
      email: 'test0@example.com',
      emailVerified: 0
    }
  ],
  unique: false
}
```

It checks for unique email so first time it gives `unique: true` but next time it gives `unique: true`.

This shouldn't happen as I'm using `for...loop` with `async...await`.

It should look like:

```json
{ email: 'test0@example.com' }
{ user: [], unique: true }
{ email: 'test1@example.com' }
{ user: [], unique: true }
```

What am I doing wrong?

It doesn't work in Puppeteer either:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/signup')

    await page.type('input[name="email"]', `test${i}@example.com`)
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]')

    await page.waitForNavigation()
    // await page.waitForSelector('#verify-email-form', {
    //   state: 'visible',
    //   timeout: 0,
    // })

    console.log(i)
  }

  await page.close()
  await browser.close()
}
```

Fwiw, I'm using React Server Actions in Next.js 14 -> https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-14-lucia-v3-sqlite-drizzle-conform-zod-email-verification-otp-server-actions/

Comment: The code looks fine to me--everything is awaited, although `await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded')` is probably unnecessary since `goto` already awaits for load by default, which is a stricter condition than domcontentloaded. Can you share the page you're automating, or a simple reproduction of it?

Comment: @ggorlen its uploaded [here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-14-lucia-v3-sqlite-drizzle-conform-zod-email-verification-otp-server-actions/blob/main/rate-limit/signup.ts)

Comment: bdw, i know it looks a bit complex but it is simple. just follow the installation script in readme. it needs unique email logic to throw the error. only commands needed after following readme are `pnpm db:delete`, `pnpm db:seed`, & `pnpm ratelimit:signup`

Comment: Sorry, it should be self-contained in the post. I'm not going to install anything. The post should be minimal so that a single problem is isolated and it's easy to reproduce for future visitors.

Comment: @ggorlen yeah dude it is isolated. how else will it work? it depends on unique email. you'll have to perform the same steps anyway. `git clone && pnpm i` idk how that is going to be different than if i make it simple. its going to be same steps anyways.

Comment: so i checked by enabling devtools & going to the network tab that there are 2 requests sent. i have to somehow make it just one to make it work.

Comment: Might be a longshot, but it could make sense running each e-mail submit in a fresh browser to make sure nothing is cached etc. By moving `browser.newPage()` and `page.close()` inside the for loop.

Comment: Have you tried to move `await page.close()` inside the loop?

Comment: @candre the reason i moved it out was because i thought the error was due to it being inside. i tried that first actually. now i retried again & it gives same error. and idk how its cached as i use sqlite database & have delete database script applied everytime. and ahmed, i did try moving page.close inside & it doesnt work either. im confused too.

Comment: `page.type('input[name="email"]', ...)` does not clear what is already in the input field. Could it be that `test0@example.com` is the default value in your sign-up page?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen no. it does clear & i've seen it type other emails too because i was running in `headless: false` mode.

Comment: I did two `await page.type('input[name="custemail"]', ...)` in succession for the same field in https://httpbin.org/forms/post and saw the concatenated value in the field.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen can you [test mine](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-14-lucia-v3-sqlite-drizzle-conform-zod-email-verification-otp-server-actions/) then? `pnpm dev` in one terminal & `pnpm ratelimit:signup` in another. it just doesn't work for some reason. i even tried `await page.type('input[name="email"]', ``)` after click but nothing works.

Comment: `page.type('input[name="email"]', ``)` has no effect at all, since it does not clear what's already in.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen then what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can push your promises to an array and use:

```
const promiseArr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    promiseArr.push(page.goto('http://localhost:3000/signup'))
    promiseArr.push(page.type('input[name="email"]', `test${i}@example.com`))
    promiseArr.push(page.click('button[type="submit"]'))
    promiseArr.push(page.waitForNavigation())
}
//rejects all when any of the promises rejects
await Promise.all(promiseArr);
```

Awaiting promises in the for loop has a different behaviour.
[Please refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410119/in-javascript-does-using-await-inside-a-loop-block-the-loop)

Upadate:
This may be a better solution due to "parallel" work of Promise.all

```
const promiseArr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    promiseArr.push(signUp(page, i));
}

//rejects all when any of the promises rejects
await Promise.all(promiseArr);
function signUp(page, i) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/signup')
        await page.type('input[name="email"]', `test${i}@example.com`)
        await page.click('button[type="submit"]')
        await page.waitForNavigation()
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. i got this error: `node_modules\.pnpm\puppeteer-core\node_modules\puppeteer-core\src\cdp\Frame.ts:191
          ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
            ^


Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at http://localhost:3000/signup
    at navigate (D:\puppeteer\node_modules\.pnpm\puppeteer-core@21.11.0\node_modules\puppeteer-core\src\cdp\Frame.ts:191:13)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at main (d:\puppeteer\rate-limit\signup.ts:37:3)` where line 37 is `await Promise.all(promiseArr)` & no the error isn't https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2902

Answer (score -4):

```
Here's how you can modify your code to address this issue:

javascript
Copy code
import { chromium } from 'playwright'

async function main() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    (async (index) => {
      await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/signup')
      await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded')

      await page.fill('input[name="email"]', `test${index}@example.com`)
      await page.click('button[type="submit"]')

      await page.waitForURL('http://localhost:3000/verify-email')
      // await page.waitForSelector('#verify-email-form', {
      //   state: 'visible',
      //   timeout: 0,
      // })

      console.log(index)
    })(i)
  }

  await page.close()
  await browser.close()
}

main()
```